# Difficulties with using function expression

Tags: javascript, function, events, dom-events, function-expression

Hopefully you will answer it !

```
var myform = document.getElementById("myform"),
saveBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
saveBtn.addEventListener("click", saveInfo);

var saveInfo = function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var dateValue = document.getElementById("inputdeadline").value;
    var todoValue = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    todoValue = todoValue.replace(/\n/g,"   ");
    if ( dateValue > 24 || dateValue <= 0) {
        myform.reset();
        return false;
    };
    if (!(todoValue)) {
        myform.reset();
        return false;
    };
    var todoObj = {
        todoValue,
        dateValue
    };
    if (localStorage.getItem("localTodoItem") === null) {
        var todoArray = [];
        todoArray.push(todoObj);
        todoArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.dateValue - b.dateValue;
        });
        localStorage.setItem("localTodoItem", JSON.stringify(todoArray));
    } else {
        var todoArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localTodoItem"));
        todoArray.push(todoObj);
        todoArray.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.dateValue - b.dateValue;
        });
        localStorage.setItem("localTodoItem", JSON.stringify(todoArray));
    };
    showTodoItems();
    myform.reset();
};
```

Here when I am using function declaration for this saveInfo function it is correctly doing all functionalities but when I am using function expression it just reload the page that's it nothing happening.
Please help me.
If you need more clarification about code  [please visit github](https://github.com/janaravi10/todoApp).

Answer (score 2):

This is because function declarations are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), whereas function expressions are not. You're using `saveInfo` before the expression is executed, which would work for a declaration but not an expression.

[Function declaration hoisting on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)